# smtp auth via boost and c++

Tags: c++, authentication, boost, smtp

i am writing an cpp smtp client using boost 1.67.
When i try to send log in data, the server returns auth error, but when i try it by hand via telnet it works.
Here is my code:

```
sktSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer("AUTH LOGIN\r\n"));
        size_t lenTemp = sktSocket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(chTemp),error);
        showResponse(chTemp.data(), lenTemp);

        std::string strUse = boost::beast::detail::base64_encode(srvTest.strUser);
        sktSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(strUse));
        sktSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer("\r\n"));
        showText(strUse);
        lenTemp = sktSocket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(chTemp), error);
        showResponse(chTemp.data(), lenTemp);

        std::string strPass = boost::beast::detail::base64_encode(srvTest.strPasswd);
        sktSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(strPass));
        sktSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer("\r\n"));
        showText(strPass);
        size_t lenLogin = sktSocket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(chLogin), error);
        showResponse(chLogin.data(), lenLogin);
```

When i run this code i got the response:

```
535 Inncorrect authentication data
```

I dont really know what i am doing wrong...
Thanks in advance

## edit------------

now i am using an own implementation for encoding to base64 and it also returns the correct encoded string as beast, but the server respoonse with 535 as before

```
unsigned int paddedCharacters = 0;
while (data.size() % 3 != 0)
{
    paddedCharacters++;
    data.push_back(0x00);
}

// Crazy typedef black magic
typedef insert_linebreaks<base64_from_binary<transform_width<const unsigned char *, 6, 8>>, 76> base64Iterator;

std::string encodedString(
    base64Iterator(data.c_str()),
    base64Iterator(data.c_str() + (data.size() - paddedCharacters)));

// Add '=' for each padded character used
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < paddedCharacters; i++)
{
    encodedString.push_back('=');
}

return encodedString;
```

Comment: You should start maybe by showing the error you got...

Comment: sorry i edited the code

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `boost::beast::detail::base64_encode`, because that is not a public interface. Anything in a `detail` namespace is an implementation detail which should not be used directly. And in fact I believe there is a bug in it. Try using a different base64 encoding function.

Comment: Ok. but when i copy and paste the output and use telnet it works

Comment: edited the question, gives same output as beast but also dont work